# query string gets ignored after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am using the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess file to send all requests to the index.php file located at the root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

As I expected, urls like **example.com/users** will result in php receiving `["q"]=> string(5) "users"` as a $_GET variable.

URLs like **example.com/users?fu=bar** on the otherhand will not result in php receiving

```
["q"]=> string(5) "users", 
["fu"]=> string(3) "bar"
```

What is happening here, and how do I modify my rule to behave that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the original query string:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
                                   ^^^ here
```